# Safari form triggering a button click instead of submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, safari

I have a form that contains several `<button>` objects, then two `<input type="text">` objects, then an `<input type="image">` object. When the user presses the enter key in one of the text fields, I expect a submit event. This is what happens on firefox and chrome. But on MacOS Safari, it triggers a click event on the first `<button>` object.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Thanks.

Edit - here's the HTML:

```
<form id="rollform" autocomplete="off">
        <div id="input">
            <input type="submit" style="display:none">
            <div id="dgrid">
                <div id="bgrid" title="Tap to Roll, Mouse Wheel to Set">
                    <button id="d100" class="bbutton checkbutton"><sup></sup><img src="d10.png" height=10><img
                            src="d10.png" height=10></button>
                    <button id="d20" class="bbutton checkbutton"><sup></sup><img src="d20.png" height=13></button>
                    <button id="d12" class="bbutton checkbutton"><sup></sup><img src="d12.png" height=13></button>
                    <button id="d10" class="bbutton checkbutton"><sup></sup><img src="d10.png" height=13></button>
                    <button id="d8" class="bbutton checkbutton"><sup></sup><img src="d8.png" height=13></button>
                    <button id="d6" class="bbutton checkbutton"><sup></sup><img src="d6.png" height=13></button>
                    <button id="d4" class="bbutton checkbutton"><sup></sup><img src="d4.png" height=13></button>
                    <button id="constant" class="bbutton checkbutton"><sup>0</sup></button>
                </div>
                <input type="text" id="d" placeholder="dice (e.g. 2d6+1)" title="Enter Dice String"
                    ondrop="event.preventDefault();">
                <input type="text" id="rollname" placeholder="quickroll name"
                    title="Name this Roll to Create a Quickroll" ondrop="event.preventDefault();">
                <div id="ad">
                    <input type="button" class="checkbutton" id="adv" title="Advantage" value="ADV">
                    <input type="button" class="checkbutton" id="dis" title="Disadvantage" value="DIS">
                    <input type="button" class="checkbutton" id="double" title="Double Dice" value="x2">
                    <input type="button" class="checkbutton" id="dm" title="DM Screen" value="DM">
                    <input type="button" class="checkbutton" id="compact" title="Compact Dice View" value="SMALL">
                    <input type="button" class="checkbutton" id="mute" title="Sound" value="MUTE">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="rollgrid">
                <input type="image" src="roll.png" id="roll" title="Tap to Roll" value="roll">
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
```

The click handler for the button with id="d100" is being triggered when the user presses enter in one of the text fields. But only on Safari.

Comment: It would help if you actually posted your code, but have you specified your button types? If not the default is `submit` so its possible the first button found is being used as the submit.

Comment: I edited to add the code. The submit handler is not being called. It's the click handler.

Comment: you need to specify `<button type="button" ...>` on your button elements.

Comment: This turned out to be the solution. Thanks you!